# Reactjs Axios Post Requests don't run

Tags: reactjs, axios

I try to make 45 post request to my database, but he always just includes a few rows and throws no errors for the others. I tried some try/catch blocks and also tried axios.all, but when I push my requests array, the requests are getting executed immediately. Sometimes just 5 requests get executed and sometimes 15, but never more.

Here is my client-side code:

```
    const insertCanteens = () => {

    let requests = [];
    let count = 0;
    canteens.map(canteen => {
        console.log("Post" + canteen.id);
        requests.push(
            Axios.post(`${databaseLocation}/api/insert`, {
            id: canteen.id,
            name: canteen.name,
            city: canteen.city
        }))
        count++;
    })
    console.log("Count: " + count);
    // axios.all(requests);
    console.log(requests);
};
```

And here my server-side code:

```
app.post('/api/insert', (req, res) => {

  const id = req.body.id;
  const name = req.body.name;
  const city = req.body.city;
  const sql = `INSERT INTO canteens (id, name, city) VALUES (?,?,?)`;
  try {
        db.query(sql, [id, name, city], (err, result) => {

              if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
              }
              else {
                    console.log("Sucessfully inserted! aaa");
                    // console.log(result);
              }
        });
  } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
  }
});
```

---

If I try it like this, I get no response or error and he still executes just a few requests.

```
    const insertCanteens = () => {

    let count = 0;
    canteens.map(canteen => {
        Axios.post(`${databaseLocation}/api/insert`, {
            id: canteen.id,
            name: canteen.name,
            city: canteen.city
            }).then( response =>
                console.log(response)
            ).catch(error => {
                console.log(error + " something went wrong!");
            })
    })
};
```

I also tried it with async and await, but same result:

```
    const insertCanteens = () => {

    let count = 0;
    canteens.map(async canteen => {
        await Axios.post(`${databaseLocation}/api/insert`, {
            id: canteen.id,
            name: canteen.name,
            city: canteen.city
        })
    })
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one?

```
const insertCanteens = async () => {
  for await (const canteen of canteens) {
    await Axios.post(`${databaseLocation}/api/insert`, {
      id: canteen.id,
      name: canteen.name,
      city: canteen.city,
    });
  }
};

// please call insertCanteens with await keyword, like this -> await insertCanteens();

await insertCanteens(); // call inside an async scope
```

Answer (score 0):

The Axios library return Promises, You are missing the `await` before the function call like this `await Axios.post(...)`, or alternatively you can use the callback pattern using `.then()` and `.catch()`.

You can read farther on [Promises at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

you can wait with Promise.all or Promise.allSetled depending of your case

```
const promises = canteens.map(canteen => {
        requests.push(
            Axios.post(`${databaseLocation}/api/insert`, {
            id: canteen.id,
            name: canteen.name,
            city: canteen.city
        }))
    })
```

promises will contain a array of pending promises from here what you can do is

```
Promises.all(promises).then(results => console.log(results)).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

where results will be an array of all the results from the pending promises, i hope this help